# ESP32: can't upload code when using WiFi.begin(ssid, password)

Tags: esp32

I'm working on a project and ran into a problem.

**Description**

I'm trying to use a esp32 as a websocket server for a project. To achive this I'm followig this tutorial http://shawnhymel.com/1675/arduino-websocket-server-using-an-esp32/. I provided the code with my SSID and password then uploaded it to the esp32.

I tested this using the google chrome extension "Simple WebSocket Client" and everything was working fine. I was able to send messages to the esp32 and receive them back in my browser. After I was convinced that everything was working fine I changed some parts of the code to suit my needs. Then when I wanted to upload the modify code I got this error message:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1yLu.png).

After a few unsuccessful google searches for a solution I tried uploading the sample code that had worked before. But I got the exact same error. After this I tried uploading the sample code peace by peace until I got the error. I can upload the complete code to the esp32 except this line `WiFi.begin(ssid, password);` in the setup. For some reason when I use `WiFi.begin(ssid, password);` in any sketch I'm unable to upload code to the esp32, I get the same error shown above.

This esp32 is also brand new and has only been connected to my pc with a usb cable.

**Question**

Does someone knows how to solve this and why it's happening?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like a strange side effect. Maybe a lib was updated - did you try the ESP32 (plain, non arduino) examples as well? Because maybe something goes wrong with the arduino stuff.

Comment: You could have a bad flash chip, or a bad USB cable, try lowering the baud rate, and trying again.

Comment: I tried using the ESP-IDF framework instead of the arduino but had the same problem. I also tried different USB cables, slower baud rate and 40MHz flash frequency, non of it helped.